# Problem in fetching data from DB and mobile number gets deleted too from DB after login 2nd time

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have authenticated my app through google sign in and after that storing the name and email-id into my Realtime DB.

I am also letting user to enter his/her mobile number and getting it verified via otp and storing it again into DB.

Now, after I go out and try to enter into the app again and sign in through same google account i want that all 3 i.e *name, email-id and mobileNo* to get fetched.

Can someone please help on where should I write what.

From my code I know that I am only inserting name and email in db. But how to fetch all 3 when I try to login again?

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            //progressDialog.hide();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            String name, email, usernameForDb;
                            GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());

                            name = signInAccount.getDisplayName();
                            email = signInAccount.getEmail();

                            usernameForDb = email.replace(".", "").replace("_", "");
                            usernameForDb = usernameForDb.substring(0, (usernameForDb.indexOf("@")));
                            String subUsername = usernameForDb.substring(0, 1);

                            UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(name, email);
                            gmfbDatabase.child(subUsername).child(usernameForDb).setValue(helperClass);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            //progressDialog.hide();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, authentication failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you can link a phone number to an existing user.

So try this:

While logging with phone link previousUser and newUser

> Automatic verify or store verificationId

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this, mCallbacks);  

mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
      @Override
      public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
          mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
      }

      @Override
      public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                           @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        mVerificationId = verificationId;
        mResendToken = token;
      }
};
```

> Manually verify

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential);
```

By doing this your Google signed user account and Phone Verification account gets linked. Now you can access phone number by `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber()`